# Windows user account just for accessing network shares on a Windows 7 machine

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares, user-accounts, samba

I would like my Xbox (Xbmc) to access my Windows 7 shares without having Guest accounts enabled and without using my Administrator account login details. I have tried making it an account called Xbox and this works fine but the Xbox account appears on the login page for Windows. Is there a way to create an account that is purely for accessing shares without it appearing as a user account????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have four questions, because I see four question marks.

No, you can't.  Users are users, and they can't really be hidden.  If you are on a domain and using domain accounts then you have a few more options as to logging in, but they are still users.

If you want easy access to the share, why not just enable anonymous access?

Comment: I guess i just wanted a finer grain approach to giving multiple people/systems differing levels of access to shares.

Comment: I really wish there was more control here, too.   Kinda  bummer that sharing is still so oldschool.  I don't know if homegroups will give any more logical control, but I doubt the would work for you since you still have the xbox.

Comment: Oh, how about making the login screen the old xp way, where you have to type in the username, not click on the picture.

Comment: See the Answer below for a suggestion that might really work.

Answer (score 1):

1. HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList
2. Create the following entry: Username: REG_DWORD
3. Set value to 0
4. Reboot

See: [Hide User Account from Welcome Screen in Windows](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-create-hidden-user-account-hide-user-account-from-welcome-screen-in-windows/)